# jquery append as 2nd last

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add item 3 before add. How do I do it? I thought about using index but then I still didnt know how to append it even if I knew where it should be placed. Anyways here is [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eC4a9/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="Add">Add</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('<div class="item">Item 3</div>').appendTo('#main');
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```js
$('<div class="item">Item 3 (inserted item)</div>').insertBefore('div.Add');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="Add">Add</div>
</div>
```

Or:

```js
$('<div class="item">Item 3 (inserted item)</div>').insertAfter('.item:last');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="Add">Add</div>
</div>
```

Though I'd suggest changing the syntax in the node-creation to:

```js
$('<div />', {
  class: 'item',
  text: 'Item 3 (inserted item)'
}).insertAfter('.item:last');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="Add">Add</div>
</div>
```

I find it just a little easier to read that way (though definitely not mandatory, or even 'best-practice').

As of editing the answer – to include the Stack Snippets – this is all easily achievable with plain JavaScript:

```js
// using Object.assign() to create an Object from the
const newDivElement = Object.assign(
                        // merger of the Element Object created
                        // by document.createElement():
                        document.createElement('div'),
                        // and the properties specified in the
                        // separate Object:
                        {
                           className: 'item',
                           textContent: 'Item 3 (inserted item)',
                         });

// using an Array literal along with the spread operator to
// convert the iterable NodeList returned by 
// document.querySelectorAll() into an Array of element nodes,
// in order to use Array methods to find the last .item element:
[...document.querySelectorAll('.item')]
  // using Array.prototype.map() to remove - and return - the
  // last Array element, which is the last .item element:
  .pop()
  // and then using Element.after() to insert the newDivElement
  // after that last .item:
  .after(newDivElement);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="Add">Add</div>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after).
  - [Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
  - [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
  - [`spread` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- jQuery:

  - [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore).
  - [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Comment: You're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! And don't worry, there's no hurry for accepting answers; the interlude may give opportunity for better answers to come in, after all. =)

Comment: Building on your answer, I used `$("div", "#main").last()` as my `insertBefore` target.  This will allow it to work even if the nodes all share the same class.

Comment: `insertBefore('div.add')` is by far the fastest option currently presented (in Chrome and Firefox), which is probably partially due to the current uniqueness of the `add` class.

Comment: @cjc343: thanks, did you JS Perf that, or test in some other way? I never considered bench-marking, to my embarrassment. =/

Comment: [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/append-after-item/3). Quick and dirty, but fulfills its purpose. The remove calls are primarily to make it possible to read, not to produce the desired result. If you remove them, the proliferation of divs with the item class will quickly slow down the selectors that rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could append after the last `.item`:

```
$('.item').last().after($('<div class="item">Item 3</div>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by finding the second last div within #main

```
var newItemHTML = '<div class="item">Item 3</div>',
    $secondLast = $('#main').find('div:last-child').prev();

$( newItemHTML ).insertAfter( $secondLast );
```